# /usr/bin/sleep causes poll object to block

Tags: python, subprocess

Using the following code, `poll_obj.poll()` blocks until sleep has completed:

```
import select, subprocess, time, fcntl, os

poll_obj = select.poll()
popen_obj = subprocess.Popen("sleep 5", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                             close_fds=True, shell=True)
fcntl.fcntl(popen_obj.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl.fcntl(popen_obj.stderr, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
poll_obj.register(popen_obj.stdout)
poll_obj.register(popen_obj.stderr)
start_time = time.time()
poll_obj.poll()
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

It is my understanding that `poll_obj.poll()` shouldn't block because the O_NONBLOCK flag is set on the FDs it tracks. It should return `None`.

Is there a way to prevent `poll_obj.poll()` from blocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`poll_obj.poll()` is supposed to block until there is something to read in a one of registered file descriptors. That blocking that you want to prevent is a desired feature. If that is not what you want, don't use `poll`.

Other commands probably either print something quickly (and poll does not have to wait for file descirptors to have something to read) or terminates quickly. The blocking time may be zero or close to zero, but `poll` follows the same logic as in `sleep` case.

`sleep` does not print anything and does not terminate quickly, so poll is blocked as expected.

**EDIT**

`O_NONBLOCK` that you used [does not affect `poll` the way you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889920/2307066). Use `poll_obj.poll(0)` to return from the call immediately even if there is nothing to read.

Comment: poll() doesn't normally block in the code I posted because the O_NONBLOCK flag is set on the FDs it tracks. You can try it with some other long running command and you'll see that poll() normally returns None.

Comment: Yeah, some way, but not the way you expect. `poll_obj.poll(0)` will do (I tried it), as I mentioned in edited answer.